# Rearranging RDD in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an RDD like this

```
[('a', [('d2', 1), ('d1', 1)]),
 ('addition', [('d2', 1)]),
 ('administrative', [('d1', 1)]),
 ('also', [('d1', 1)])]
```

I want an output to look like

```
a#d2:1;d1:1
addition#d2:1
administrative#d1:1
also#d1:1
```

I was trying to remove brackets first in order to achieve the output

```
rdd_new.map(lambda x: re.sub('\(|\)', '', str(x)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map each rdd entry to a string using the suitable string methods:

```
result = rdd.map(lambda r: r[0] + '#' + ';'.join(['%s:%d' % (i[0], i[1]) for i in r[1]]))

result.collect()
# ['a#d2:1;d1:1', 'addition#d2:1', 'administrative#d1:1', 'also#d1:1']
```

Comment: can we get d2 before d1 like #d1:1;d2:1

Comment: You can sort: `result = rdd.map(lambda r: r[0] + '#' + ';'.join(['%s:%d' % (i[0], i[1]) for i in sorted(r[1])]))`